# How do I find event ranges overlapping a set of hours in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, datetime

Assuming I have table called `events` with the columns

```
INT  id
DATETIME start_time
DATETIME end_time
```

how would I find all rows where any part of the time range from start_time to end_time falls within a certain hour range?

For example, I may want to find rows where the events had some portion of them during the 8-10pm hour range.

Something like

```
select * from events where (hour(start_time) IN (20, 21, 22)) or (hour(end_time) IN (20, 21, 22))
```

would work, except for events that started before 8pm and ended after 11pm.

Lastly, it has to work across day boundaries, so a range like 23-2 (11pm - 2am) should also work.

Unfortunately I'm unable to modify the schema of the table.

Comment: I don't understand: before you say _where the events had some portion of them during the 8-10pm hour range_ and then you say _a range like 23-2 (11pm - 2am) should also work_... so, what's the right one?

Comment: I need to support arbitrary hour ranges. So 1-6, 3-10, 23-2, 10-4, whatever.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to make this work with the day boundaries requirement. It's ugly, but it seems to cover all the cases.

While you could write a stored procedure to do it, it's easier to express in Java, so:

```
public void checkEvents (int[][] events, int startHour, int endHour)    

  final int START         = 0;
  final int END           = 1;
  final int HOURS_PER_DAY = 24;

  for (int[] event : events) {

    int start = startHour;
    int end = (endHour < startHour) ? endHour + HOURS_PER_DAY : endHour;

    int eventStart = event[START];
    int eventEnd = (event[END] < event[START]) ? event[END] + HOURS_PER_DAY : event[END];

    if (checkOverlap(result, event, start, end, eventStart, eventEnd))
    || (checkOverlap(result, event, start, end, eventStart + HOURS_PER_DAY, eventEnd + HOURS_PER_DAY))
      || (checkOverlap(result, event, start + HOURS_PER_DAY, end + HOURS_PER_DAY, eventStart, eventEnd))
       || (!checkOverlap(result, event, start + HOURS_PER_DAY, end + HOURS_PER_DAY, eventStart + HOURS_PER_DAY, eventEnd + HOURS_PER_DAY);
          System.out.println("overlapped!");
  }
}

private boolean checkOverlap(ArrayList<int[]> result, int[] event, int start, int end, int eventStart, int eventEnd) {

  if ((eventStart >= start && eventStart < end) || (eventStart < start && eventEnd > start)) {
    return true;
  }

  return false;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Assuming the start_time and end_time fields are datetime fields, then

```
SELECT *
FROM events
WHERE (start_time <= $event_end_time) AND (end_time >= $event_start_time)
```

It's a bit counterintuitive, but if you look at it on a timeline:

A&B are your limit fenceposts. X&Y are the start_time and end_time fields:

```
         A   B
p = -----------   event falls outside the boundaries
     X Y

         A    B
q = -----------   partial overlap
     X    Y

       A   B
r = -----------   partial overlap again
        X    Y

       A   B
s = -----------  full overlap
     X       Y

      A  B
t = -----------  outside boundaries
           X Y
```

You're interested in cases Q, R, and S. You'll notice that for those 3 cases, Y is ALWAYS >= A, and X is always <= B

Comment: +1 for the illustration. It lacks the case where A <= X <= B <= Y, but the invariant still holds.

Comment: Unfortunately I'm not looking for events between a definitive start and end time, I'm looking for events that are during specific hours of the day.

Comment: The same logic applies. Just do the appropriate conversions to look at just time periods. if you're looking at multiple periods, then run the query multiple times, build a union query that has all the periods, or build a long "if / else / else / else" sequence for each period.

Comment: I'm not sure that's the same thing. I'm talking about time periods on *any* day. So I would want to find an event that happened during the 8pm hour on Monday or Tuesday. It's the hours of the day I care about, not a specific set of dates during a year.

Comment: Yes, so... `WHERE time(start_time) <= time($event_end_time) etc...`. The time embedded in the start/endtime fields will be invariant.

Comment: but how would that work for time ranges that span day boundaries, like 11pm - 2am?

Comment: Then you've got a bit of a problem. Probably have to revamp those ranges to add a 'day', so it'd be 0:23:00.00 -> 1:02:00.00